# How to maintain popular but aging questions

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I have a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate) with >160 votes at the time of writing, which has attracted several bounties but no answers yet. The post is almost a year old, but now there are newer versions of the library in question and the compiler, both of which could potentially affect answers or make the question no long applicable. In addition, some users have given partial answers in comments which have helped me realize the "core" of my original question.

I'd like to rewrite the whole thing, updating it for:

- the status with the latest GHC and syntactic library
- remove answered parts of the question, or at least de-emphasize them

I'm hoping this will clarify the question, which I feel is a bit unweildy and out of date. On the other hand, I'm apprehensive about rewriting a question that so many people felt was worth asking, and I'm unsure how to go about it.

I'm in a similar situation with these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502335/transitivity-of-auto-specialization-in-ghc), which have similar issues: they were written so long ago, the version of the compiler has changed at least twice, and they could stand to be rewritten for clarity. They both attracted answers, but I think it's safe to say they are not quite what people were looking for (myself included). I take some portion of the blame there because the questions could have been clearer in the first place. So again: update or leave as-is? Should I leave the original question below the updated version? Do you have a good example where someone else did this (as far as formatting, recognition of answers-via-comment, etc)?

Comment: This is kind of tough because there are so many "if"s and "why"s. Take your [first example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684947/when-is-xallowambiguoustypes-appropriate). Why did you put a bounty on it if there are newer versions? Then,  *"In addition, some users have given partial answers in comments which have helped me realize the "core" of my original question.*", why not post that as an answer and accept it then write a new question relating to the newer versions? I don't have expert knowledge in that area so I may be way off here.

Comment: If you do post a new, related question then I would link to the old one if possibly relevant. Which it sounds like it would be.

Comment: You can't invalidate an answer since there are none.  But there's currently a bounty on the question, the user surely meant to inspire an answer to the existing question instead of the one you want to ask now.  Tough call.  You could, perhaps, post a comment to one of his posts and ask him if it is okay to edit the question.

Comment: @codeMagic Most (all?) of the bounties were posted by *other* users, not me. If I put a bounty on it (not sure how to tell), it was quite a while back.

Comment: @Eric yes, I just realized it wasn't you so as Hans said, I wouldn't change it's meaning at all without asking the user who placed the current bounty

Comment: @Eric: Look at the revisions link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23684947/revisions 4 Bounties for a total of 450 yet, the highest from you. BTW: There are 4 deleted non-answers...